# Div not covering children

Tags: html, css

I want to include my "content" div and "sidebar" div inside my "main" div, but it does not work. What is the issue here?

As you can see the "heading" and "sidebar" is not inside the white are which is supposed to be the main div

```css
body {
color:#333333;
background-color:#A6BFB3;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
width:100%;
height:100%;}

#wrapper {
width:960px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color:#fff;
}

#header {
width:100%;
border-bottom: 5px solid #4A8520;
height: auto;
}

#header img {
width:100%;
}


#main {
background-color:#fff;
width:100%;
padding:20px;
}

#content {
width:70%;
float:left;

}

#sidebar {
width:25%;
float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <header id="header">
        <img src="http://kurkuma-kapseln.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Header_Kurkuma_Kapseln.jpg">
   </header>
   <div id="main">
       <div id="content">
          <h1> Heading</h1>
       </div>
       <div id="sidebar">
          sidebar
       </div>
   </div>
<!-- Ende Main -->

</div>
<!-- Ende Wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

In particular `display:inline-block;` is important. `box-sizing:border-box` is a nice solution to let it show nice. The padidng is included in the div's total width and height.

```css
#main {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe these two links can explain it to you: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try **removing** `float:left`,
and **Add** `display:inline-block` to css of `content` div.